# Can't paint objects from an instantiated class in another class

Tags: java, swing, colors

I can't paint my rectangle and circle in a class. The class that this forms have been created is instantiated in my main class, but I can't paint there, only in their own classes.

I'm not good with words. Just look at code.

Class Game:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D graficos = (Graphics2D) g;


    /* switch (corAtualR) {
    case PRETO: {

        graficos.setColor(Color.black);
        graficos.fillRect((int) mb.x, (int) mb.y, 60, 60);
        break;
    }
    case VERMELHO: {

        graficos.setColor(Color.red);
        graficos.fillRect((int) mb.x, (int) mb.y, 60, 60);
        break;
    }

    case AZUL: {

        graficos.setColor(Color.blue);
        graficos.fillRect((int) mb.x, (int) mb.y, 60, 60);
        break;
    }

    case AMARELO: {

        graficos.setColor(Color.yellow);
        graficos.fillRect((int) mb.x, (int) mb.y, 60, 60);
        break;
    }

    case VERDE: {

        graficos.setColor(Color.green);
        graficos.fillRect((int) mb.x, (int) mb.y, 60, 60);
        break;

    } 

    default: {

        graficos.setColor(Color.black);
        graficos.fillRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
        break;
    }


    }  */


    mb.paint(graficos);
    graficos.dispose();

}

}
```

The commented-out code is the code that I couldn't paint from my instantiated class.

And here is my MenuBar class:

```
// Ações do Retângulo
public void acoesRetangulo() {

    // Action Listeners dos botões para pintar o retângulo da respectiva cor.

    pretoR.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            corAtualR = PRETO;

        }
    });

}

}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    switch (corAtualR) {
    case PRETO: {

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect((int) x, (int) y, 60, 60);
        break;
    }
    case VERMELHO: {

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect((int) x, (int) y, 60, 60);
        break;
    }

    case AZUL: {

        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect((int) x, (int) y, 60, 60);
        break;
    }

    case AMARELO: {

        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillRect((int) x, (int) y, 60, 60);
        break;
    }

    case VERDE: {

        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect((int) x, (int) y, 60, 60);
        break;

    }

    default: {

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
        break;
    }
    }


    g.dispose();
}

}
```

See that the same code, without the instances of course (mb, of MenuBar), works properly in my program.

Just awaiting answers, sorry about my newbish on that hehe. (and my english)

Comment: Please, remove uninteresting parts of your codes.

Comment: You've deleted too much code, and now folks can't see that you're misusing inheritance. It's a fine art, trying to figure out what code to show and what to delete, but you're much better off creating and posting a totally new **small** program that demonstrates your problem for us, a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yeah, thats what i was thinking.

Comment: sorry, and thanks for the other answer

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be misusing inheritance: MenuBar should most definitely **not** extend the Game class. By doing this, you change the state of Game variables, but they're not those of the Game object that is actually displayed, and you end up just fooling yourself into thinking that your code might work. Instead the MenuBar class should ***contain*** a Game variable and that variable should refer to the actual visible Game object.

As an aside:

- You should do all your painting in the JPanel's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method, not the `paint(Graphics g)` method.
- Never call `dipose()` on a Graphics object given you from the JVM or you risk painting problems down-stream.

Comment: hmm, i did it, i changed paint to paintComponent, and droped the Game extend on MenuBar, put it wont work yet.

Comment: @Memphys: `"It won't work"` doesn't give us much to go on, much that we can use to figure out *why* it's not working. I suggest that you simplify things greatly, create your [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), one that has two classes, one that has drawings on it and the other with menu code, and then post it. Let us experience your problem and thereby better be able to present you with a solution.